# Architecture of an app using Core Data and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform, watchkit

I struggle with with building a To do app that will download activities from Parse , save them with Core Data and then they will be showed on Apple Watch. I'd like to ask if this is a more or less proper approach to do it:

1. In viewWillLoad we check if there is an internet connection:

   - if **TRUE** we loop over activities in core data and compare them with those from Parse

     - if they compare we do nothing and prepare cells using info from Core Data
     - if they do not compare we add them to Core data and prepare cells
   - if **FALSE** we prepare cells with info from Core Data

I'm trying to implement my way, but have a problem. Data fetched from parse shown only at the second launch of app. The do not fetch and show at the same time.
My properties

```
var medicines : [Medicine] = [Medicine]()
var frc :NSFetchedResultsController!
var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Medicine")
```

My methods to get the data:

```
// MARK: - Fetching
func fetchFromParse() {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Medicine", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Medicine")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                let medicine = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)
                if let  name = object["medicineName"] as? String,
                        amount = object["amountQuantity"] as? String {
                    //save to  Core Data
                    medicine.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                    medicine.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")


                    do {
                        try self.context.save()

                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


func fetchFromCoreData() {

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        medicines = results  as! [Medicine]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }


}
```

I call them in viewWillAppear:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        //fetching data from Parse

        fetchFromParse()
        fetchFromCoreData()

    } else {
        //fetching data from Core data
        fetchFromCoreData()
        logOutButton.enabled = false

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to set up a background task to fetch the data with Parse and stick new entries in your core data store, and when new items are detected, to refresh the table on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, agree this is the right way to go, just make sure you use a NSFetchedResultsController with the UITableView so that any changes received from the background thread are automatically reflected.  Avoid using the main thread for remote calls or processing data if you can.

Comment: I don't really know how to make it. Could you check my solution ?